# MySql LEFT JOIN returns wrong first in PHP page, but correct results in MYSQL command line

Tags: php, mysql, left-join

We added two columns to our main MySQL table (named objects), a column for quantity and a column for id of the units. If the quantity and/or units are unknown, those columns are set to NULL.

We wanted to join this table with the unittype table to display the name of the units (pounds, pages, grams, whatever).

When I run the SELECT inside MYSQL's command line client, it returns the expected the results.  When my PHP page runs the query, the first row shows values from the wrong side of the join.

Example:
The tables being joined are objects and unittypes with these definitions

```
mysql> show create table objects;
CREATE TABLE `objects` (
  `objId` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `description` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `quantity` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `unitid` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `create_date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `modify_date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`objId`),
  KEY `unitid` (`unitid`),
  CONSTRAINT `objects_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`unitid`) REFERENCES `unittypes` (`unitId`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4735 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

and:

```
mysql> show create table unittypes;
CREATE TABLE `unittypes` (
  `unitId` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `description` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `create_date` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `modify_date` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`unitId`),
  UNIQUE KEY `name` (`name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Sample rows:

```
Unittypes:

+--------+------+--------------+-
| unitId | name | description  | 
+--------+------+--------------+-
|      1 | Each | Each         | 

Objects:
```

```
+-------+---------------------------------------+-------------+----------+--------+
| objId | NAME                                  | description | quantity | unitid | 
+-------+---------------------------------------+-------------+----------+--------+
|  1018 | UNKNOWN cables                        | NULL        |   NULL   |  NULL  |  
|  3466 | UNKNOWN replies                       | NULL        |   NULL   |  NULL  | 
+-------+---------------------------------------+-------------+----------+--------+
|   722 | Soundgarden-Loudest Love              | NULL        |        1 |      1 |   
|  4703 | Soundgarden-Live FROM The Artists Den | NULL        |        1 |      1 |
+-------+---------------------------------------+-------------+----------+--------+
```

Sample join query:

```
SELECT o.objid, o.name, o.description, 
       o.quantity, u.name, u.description, o.create_date, o.modify_date 
FROM objects AS o 
LEFT JOIN unittypes u USING(unitid) 
WHERE o.NAME LIKE '%Soundgarden-L%'
```

In MYSql command line client it returns:

```
+-------+---------------------------------------+-------------+----------+------+-------------+---------------------+---------------------+    
| objid | name                                  | description | quantity | name | description | create_date         | modify_date         |
+-------+---------------------------------------+-------------+----------+------+-------------+---------------------+---------------------+
|   722 | Soundgarden-Loudest Love              | NULL        |        1 | Each | Each        | 2017-04-01 05:44:56 | 2020-01-15 08:59:45 |    
|  4703 | Soundgarden-Live From The Artists Den | NULL        |        1 | Each | Each        | 2019-09-17 21:52:26 | 2020-01-15 08:59:45 |
+-------+---------------------------------------+-------------+----------+------+-------------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

In PHP page, it returns (PHP page returned the expected results without a join:

```
objid   name    description quantity    create_date modify_date

722 Each    Each    1   2017-04-01 05:44:56 2020-01-15 08:59:45

4703    Soundgarden-Live From The Artists Den   NULL    1   Each    Each    2019-09-17 21:52:26 2020-01-15 08:59:45
```

Result set has 3 rows.

Example when unittypes doesn't have a matching row:

In command line client:

```
SELECT o.objid, o.name, o.description, 
       o.quantity, u.name, u.description, o.create_date, o.modify_date 
FROM objects AS o 
LEFT JOIN unittypes u USING(unitid) 
WHERE o.NAME LIKE '%unknown %';
```

result:

```
+-------+--------------------------------------------------+-------------+----------+------+-------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| objid | name                                             | description | quantity | name | description | create_date         | modify_date         |
+-------+--------------------------------------------------+-------------+----------+------+-------------+---------------------+---------------------+
|  1018 | Unknown cables                                   | NULL        |     NULL | NULL | NULL        | 2017-06-27 02:22:12 | 2017-06-27 02:22:12 |    
|  3466 | Unknown replies                                | NULL        |     NULL | NULL | NULL        | 2018-11-05 01:45:17 | 2018-11-05 01:45:17 |
|
```

In PHP page:

```
objid   name    description quantity    create_date modify_date
1018    NULL    NULL    NULL    2017-06-27 02:22:12 2017-06-27 02:22:12

3466    Unknown replies NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    2018-11-05 01:45:17 2018-11-05 01:45:17
```

I get the same results using the join syntax

left join unittypes u on  o.unitid = u.unitid

PHP code that performs query:

```
if ($result =  $GLOBALS['DB']->query($selObj)) {
        if ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

            $row_cnt = $result->num_rows;

            echo '<table><tr>';
            foreach(array_keys($row) as $heading) echo "<th>$heading</th>";
            echo '</tr>';

            /* process result set */
            do {
                echo '<tr>';
                foreach($row as $item) echo '<td>'.($item==NULL?'NULL':$item).'</td>';
                echo '</tr>';
            } while ($row = $result->fetch_row()); // get next result set
            echo '</table>';
            printf("Result set has %d row%s.<br><br>", $row_cnt,($row_cnt==1?"":"s"));
            $result->close();
        } else echo 'Empty result set<br><br>';
    } else echo $DB->error;
```

I would expect the same query to behave the same way in both examples.
I would have guessed that the command-line and the PHP simply hand off a string to mySQL to process, but there is obviously some difference I'm not seeing.

Is there something weird about how the PHP passes the query in; does MYsql not handle joins through that interface properly; is the code wrong (it works without a join)?

(I also asked this at https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/258940/200179)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two columns called `name`. The second will overwrite the first.

You should alias them to have distinct names. `` select `o`.`name` as `o_name` ... ``

In your case, the reason why only the first row is affected is because you use `fetch_assoc` to get that, but then `fetch_row` to get the others (and `fetch_row` works because it ignores column names entirely)

Comment: Excellent!  That fixed it, and you explained exactly what was going on.  I wasn't aware of fetch_assoc vs fetch_row previously either. Thanks